# Scaling custom stacking symbols like parentheses

Tags: scaling, stacking-symbols

I have created two custom symbols that I'd like to use like parentheses. It works fine when what is inside is in normal size, but when there is a bigger symbol, it does not scale, even if I use `\left` and `\right`.

Here is a minimal example of what I have been able to do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\ltirarr}{\mathopen{\langle\kern-0.21em\mid}}
\newcommand{\rtirarr}{\mathclose{\mid\kern-0.21em\rangle}}

\begin{document}
Inline: $\ltirarr x \rtirarr$. Display:
\[\ltirarr \sum_{x=1}^n x \rtirarr\]
\end{document}
```

Which renders this:

[image]

Could you help scaling these symbols? (Or maybe find them in a package, I couldn't find them, even non-scaling versions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, I use the `scalerel` package to scale the custom symbol, but limiting its overall width to 10pt.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand{\ltirarr}{\mathopen{\langle\kern-0.21em\mid}}
\newcommand{\rtirarr}{\mathclose{\mid\kern-0.21em\rangle}}

\begin{document}
Inline: $\ltirarr x \rtirarr$. Display:
\[\scaleleftright[10pt]{\ltirarr}{\sum_{x=1}^n x}{\rtirarr}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason, this is not rendered as nicely on mine. The symbols are still too small (they get bigger - and also wider - when I increase the width limit), it also gets very small when using the scaling on normalsize math. Any tips to fix it?

Comment: @jedidreyfus Off the top of my head, the only thing I can think is to check if you have the latest package: https://ctan.org/pkg/scalerel.  Also, i would not use it on normalsize math, unless there is an alternate reason to.

Comment: I fixed it, it was this weird line that was in my preamble for some reason: ```\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
\graphicspath{{.}}```